# skia decoder->decode returned false when download image and display in imageview

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-imageview, inputstream, android-bitmap

i have a php page which return image from php page in json format

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM image_table WHERE email_id = '$email'");

if (!empty($result)) {
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $user = array();
        $user["image"] = base64_encode($result["image"]);
        $response["success"] = 1;
       $response["image_table"] = array();

        array_push($response["image_table"], $user);
      echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No Image  found";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

which return me something like

```
  {"success":1,"image_table":[{"image":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAIAAAD\/gAIDAAAAA3NCSVQFBgUzC42AAAAgAElEQVR4nDS70Y8c2XXm+WXUiewTyYhi3GIGO4Nkkgx2J1tZraLMsptyU6sWRMGtdQte2dLsGB4NsLPQww4wuy8LP
```

when i use this in my class imageview dosent show my image....and asynctask activity continuesly running......

```
 class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivityMap.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Image. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", email));
            json= jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_img_address, "GET", params);

            Log.d("Image: ", json.toString());

            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    address = json.getJSONArray(TAG_IMAGE_TABLE);
                    for (int i = 0; i < address.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = address.getJSONObject(i);
                         image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
                         InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(image.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                         bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream); 


                    } 
                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return null;
    }

protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        ivProperty.setImageBitmap(bmp);


    }

}
```

when i use this in my asuncktask....i have one more logcat result ..i.e

```
03-31 18:16:03.358: D/skia(2622): --- decoder->decode returned false
```

what is the issue and how to solve it......thx in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this,

```
String strPicture;
for (int i = 0; i < address.length(); i++) {
 JSONObject c = address.getJSONObject(i);
 strPicture= c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
 byte bytePic[] = null;
        try {
            bytePic = Base64.decode(strPicture, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (bytePic != null) {
            ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    bytePic);
            Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            imageStream.reset();
            imageView.setImageBitmap(theImage); //Setting image to the image view
        }
}
```

Comment: 04-01 12:52:09.839: D/skia(2771): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
and this is my json reponse @HappyMan
04-01 12:52:09.723: D/Image:(2771): {"success":1,"image_table":[{"image":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD\/4RDcRXhpZgA‌​ATU0AKgAAAAgABAE7AAIAAAAGAAAISodpAAQAAAABAAAIUJydAAEAAAAMAAAQyOocAAcAAAgMAAAAPgAA‌​AAAc6gAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA‌​AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA