# BitmapFactory decodeByteArray returns null on well formed Base64 String

Tags: android, base64, bitmapfactory

Having researched everywhere I could, the following code in Android doesn't work:

```
String base_64_source="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";
byte[] data = Base64.decode(base_64_source, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```

the returned bitmap is **null**! I know for a fact that the base64 source is valid by putting it as html here:

```
<img src="data:image:png;base64,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"/>
```

you could also try it here:

http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Any thought anyone? I wonder if the code underlying the **BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray** is faulty.

Comment: Your code works fine, when tested on a Nexus 9 running Android 7.0.

Comment: Wow, I'm running Android 6.0.1, API 23 and it doesn't !!! How can I make my code work in all devices then?!
@CommonsWare

Comment: Hmmmm... I can reproduce your problem on a Nexus 5 running Android 6.0.1. It looks like Skia is not happy about the input (`D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false`). [This fix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29384990/115145) (switching to `ByteArrayInputStream`) did not help. My guess is that it's tied to the image itself, not the base64 decoding. You could confirm this by saving `data` to a file and comparing it with the original image (or a known-good decoded version of the image).

Comment: @CommonsWare
Thanks, so we now know for a fact that the image is decoded and made into Bitmap on a later version of android. I wonder if there was a bug in skia that they've fixed. How can I get the code for that to include it in my app do you think?

Comment: Skia is native code, and I know of no good way for you to include your own copy. `BitmapFactory` [still uses native code as of Android 7.0](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-cts-7.0_r3/graphics/java/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.java). I don't have any great ideas for you, other than to try to control this at the server if possible (e.g., figure out what sorts of images fail, then avoid serving those sorts of images).

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same problem. I didn't run your base_64_source but I used my own image. What I have learned is only some LG devices running Android 7.0 have this problem. Here are tested devices.

**decodeByteArray Working**

- LG G4, Android 6.0
- LG Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1

  - This is strange because @CommonsWare reproduced this problem on same device
- ASUS Nexus 7, Android 6.0.1
- Motorola XT1032, Android 5.1

**decodeByteArray Not working**

- LG Nexus 5X, Android 7.0
- LG V10, Android 7.0

I couldn't find same issue anywhere but here. My workaround is that if decodeByteArray return is null, I create new Bitmap and decode byte[] like https://stackoverflow.com/a/38530866/7303462

Comment: I've figured out the problem. It depends on the way the image is generated and saved. I changed the way I was storing images and used a different library and the whole problem was resolved. I tested roughly 177,000 different images! :-)